# When does a Rope become a Line?

Tags: ropes, sailing, terminology

As pointed out in a [comment by cobaltduck](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/14189/what-type-of-rope-to-use-for-the-mainsheet-of-sunfish#comment34729_14189) in the question [What type of rope to use for the mainsheet of sunfish?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/14189) the proper name for rope when used on a boat is line.

If I go to the store and buy a length of rope and put it on my boat it is now a line.

When does it become a line instead of a rope?

- When it becomes attached to the boat.
- When I took a sailing class and learned better.
- When I buy it and it does not belong to the store any longer.
- Or ...

Comment: This seems so weird to me: The "rope" does not change into a "line". It is simply that mountaineers (not exclusively) call this item "rope" and "sailors" (not exclusively) call the same (maybe just almost the same) item "line". This is called jargon.

Comment: it has always been a line, if it is to be used on a boat.

Comment: Tried to clearify the Q. It is about defining what you call a rope and a line, so comparing specifications.

Comment: @Wills Well that is a different question. nivag addresses this new question, cobaltduck the old. In my opinion it is now too broad: There is not such a thing as *the* rope or *the* line. Comparing such umbrella terms is not really meaningful.

Comment: @Wills That is not a clarifying change.  That is changing the question.  Specification versus context is not the same.

Comment: Rolled back the edit

Comment: This has become too broad - answerers have tackled two different versions. Editing to change the meaning of a question does this - so please avoid doing that.

Comment: Voting to reopen, the question has been rolled back to it's original version.

Comment: @JamesJenkins I still don't get what you are asking. These are two words for the same thing in different contexts or by different groups. There is no such thing as a transformation from rope to line. Can you clarify this?

Comment: @imsodin If I say [Dihydrogen monoxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihydrogen_monoxide_hoax) in place of the more common alternate name [i.e. this tag](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water) there is no physical transformation, but the attributes change. While you can use the substance/object interchangeably you can't use the words interchangeably. The change of the attributes in the case of rope/line is defined by outdoor activities, so I believe the question has a home here, rather than at [English.SE](http://english.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My answer is that as soon as a thing begins being *thought* of, even potentially, as being involved in a sailing craft, it takes on the sailing term.

If I am going to the hardware store to buy something to make a leash for my dog, or to hang stuff up in my shed, that's rope.  If I am going to buy the same exact thing to become a traveler or a painter, that's line.

The same can be said of a toilet becoming a head, or a piece of wood being a floor/deck or a wall/ bulkhead, or a mattress being for a bed or a berth.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I would rarely call anything a line. More specific terminology, such as sheet or halyard, is generally more helpful. But anyway, I would say a rope is a line when you put it on a boat. Until then it is just a bit of rope that you could do anything else with.

Also note that in many ways a line is more general than just rope and can refer to cable or chain on larger boats.